# Import a custom class in another folder in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a folder caller logging and a Java class called AppLogger in it. How do I import the class Applogger into MainActivity?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this way:

import package_name.folder_name.java_class_name;

for you try this:

`import mobileaccess.hid.com.hidmobileaccess.logging.AppLogger;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import packkage.AppLogger;
```

Or if static

```
import static packkage.AppLogger;
```

Comment: Does not work. It doesn't even give an option for AppLogger

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
import logging.AppLogger;
```